Apacite not working in Texmaker
I am trying to compile bibliography in Texmaker 6.0.0. with the Miktex distribution using the apacite package and bibliography style with the natbibapa option. However, when I compile it (the whole process of pdf>bibtex>pdfx2) it throws the next message:

Package natbib Warning: Citation `albanesi2023families' on page 1
undefined on input line 61.

One of this for each cited piece. Any help solving this issue would be much appreciated, below the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@book{goldin2021career,
  title={Career and family: Women’s century-long journey toward equity},
  author={Goldin, Claudia},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Princeton University Press}
}
@incollection{albanesi2023families,
  title={Families, labor markets, and policy},
  author={Albanesi, Stefania and Olivetti, Claudia and Petrongolo, Barbara},
  booktitle={Handbook of the Economics of the Family},
editor={Shelly Lundberg and Alessandra Voena},
  volume={1},
  pages={255--326},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{gallup2017towards,
  title={Towards a better future for women and work: Voices of women and men},
  author={Gallup, Inc. and ILO },
  journal={Gallup and the International Labour Organization, Technical report},
  year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{goldin2021career}

\citet{albanesi2023families}

\citet{gallup2017towards}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}

And here my Texmaker preferences


Can you show your .blg file?

nop, I think it has not generated it, although the process exited normally

... then it probably did not run bibtex.

Can you show your texmaker preferences?

Or compile with latexmk, this should automatically run the necessary tools.

I have edited my question, at the end you can find the preferences.

Replace biber % with bibtex %

Great!!! it worked perfectly, many thanks!!

In the entry with author={Gallup, Inc. and ILO }, both "authors" are not persons but corporate entities. To prevent BibTeX's parser from treating "Inc." as the given name and "Gallup" as the surname of the first author, please change the field to author={{Gallup, Inc.} and {ILO}}.

I've also taken the liberty of making your code example minimal.
